# Cannon MG6250 Printer wont work with Bionic Beaver

Tags: printing

I run my printer using wireless mode and since changing to Ubuntu18.4 the printer will no longer work. It shows up in the selected printers but tells me that it is not in usable. I have downloaded the drivers and they seem to install but still can not use printer. it works fine with earlier versions of Ubuntu